# Does HONDA have a model called CBR 660RR?

Tags: road-vehicles

http://www.sagmart.com/news/Automobiles/honda-is-going-to-reveal-its-new-bike-cbr-600rr-this-december

> The design of this new CBR is awesome; you surely skip a beat when it
>   passes through the way. With its stylish aerodynamic design, this bike
>   shows all its power and what it is capable of. **CBR 600RR** has **12 spoke
>   alloy wheels** which add a perfect sporty look that was missing from its
>   previous version. New CBR has advanced and power braking system that
>   can help you to stop the bike in no time even at high speed. **CBR 660RR**
>   sports bike has **599cc** liquid cooled inline engine with four valves
>   that churns the power output of **102bhp**. With its comfortable seating
>   and superior handling you can enjoy long drive without any break.

Based on link above is there such a model called HONDA CBR 660RR? or is it a fail project? or is it just a fake? When you google for it you can find some other 660RR references but most of them actually refers to CBR 600RR.

(little note: couldnt find a 'bikes' or 'motorbikes' tag and couldnt create one so i used cars tag instead)

Comment: Umm also i would like to be noted about my mistakes in this question. What is the cause of -2 points here?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I can guess the downvote was because your question doesn't appear to be challenging a notable claim (see the faq http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable)

Comment: @ColinPickard I see! At that moment that news sounded like a notable claim but i understand now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be a typo.  [A search of the Honda Powersports site finds no results for 660RR](http://powersports.honda.com/search.aspx?q=660RR) and the claimed specs (599cc, 102hp) are the same those of 2013 model of the CBR600RR.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if there was an unsuccessfull model they made. Off course they would not wanna show it in their website. Anyways you have given a good answer. Maybe i hoped for more..